# How to register id in page url?

Tags: django

On the first page there is a button to go to the second page. Does the project itself appear on the first page? for example, the address is `project/1/`. After going to the second page, the address is `conclusion1/example/`, and I need `/conclusion1/example/1/`. How to do this?

conclusion1 urls.py

```
url(r'^example/$, 'conclusion1.views.example', name='example'),
```

main urls.py

```
url(r'^conclusion1/', include('conclusion1.urls')),
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey you just have to do:

```
url(r'^example/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$, 'conclusion1.views.example_detail', name='example_detail')
```

And to access to this url it is just:

```
HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('example_detail', kwargs={'id': 1}))
```

Comment: I have a lot of projects, the ID itself should be displayed, if the project number 5, then the conclusion 5

Comment: Hey, I don't get you. Can you explain it more extensively?